# Datagrid without dependencies

Tags: datagrid, slickgrid, handsontable

In one of my projects I have to use a datagrid that uses pure js. I came across few high performance grids on github. I never had to use them before so, came here for an advice which one to chose. I found a cool comparison http://jspreadsheets.com and I'm like 50/50 for first two options. Someone used slickgrid or handsontable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a bit broad so you might get people voting it down however, what you could do is give more insight on your project. Think about how anyone would answer this question. If we don' know what you need the datagrid for, then there are an infinite number of arguments against and in favor of all. Consider explaining your use case and doing some research yourself.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I'm looking for a quick way to implement filtering and displaying only rows with chosen data. I'm not going to let user edit data, but I want to let them change row colors by a button clink. There will be about 1500-1800 rows with 11 columns so I guess a performance could be a problem.